# How to Connect Meteor Server to External Websocket / Socket IO API?

Tags: meteor, websocket, socket.io

In my Meteor 1.0 app, I'm trying to connect the server to an external websocket (socket-io) API provided by a company called BTC China. Details on the API can be found [here](http://btcchina.org/websocket-api-market-data-documentation-en#javascript).

All the examples I have found are for the client. How does one subscribe to a socket-io API on the Meteor server? There doesn't seem to be a meteor package for this on `atmospherejs.com` and I'm struggling a bit. I've installed the `socket-io` NPM package and gotten this far:

```
var socket = Npm.require('socket.io').listen('https://websocket.btcchina.com/');
socket.emit('subscribe', ['marketdata_cnybtc']);
socket.emit('subscribe', ['marketdata_cnyltc']);
socket.emit('subscribe', ['marketdata_btcltc']);
socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log("Hello,btcc!");
      socket.on('trade', function (data) {
        console.log("Hello,trade!");
          console.log(data);});
});
```

But this returns the following error: `TypeError: Object https://websocket.btcchina.com/ has no method 'listeners'`, which means I'm defining the `socket` variable incorrectly. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a new Meteor package `joncursi:socket-io-client` to solve this problem. Please see https://atmospherejs.com/joncursi/socket-io-client for more detail and example usage. Since I've bundled the NPM binaries into a package, so you won't have to worry about installing NPM packages, declaring `NPM.require()` dependencies, etc. And best of all, you can deploy to `.meteor.com` without a hitch.

Comment: Would the prepackacged npm binaries be a problem if meteorhacks:npm package is already installed?

Comment: @battery shoudn't cause a conflict. you can just simply use this package without having to worry about configuring any of that NPM business